# Storing IPs inside of the Database for user's activity log

Tags: php, database

I'm building a sort of login system for my website and I want to log user's activity in the database. The problem is with storing the IPs of the user each time.

I have the users table with all the user's details, such as username, pass etc. But if I'll add another column with the IPs, the only way to store it(that I am aware) is JSON kind of format(the TEXT one). So it would be something like:

username: theuser
password: thepassword
etc...
IPs: { '27/04/2018 13:05': '127.0.0.1', '28/04/2018 16:28': '127.0.0.2', etc }

But...

1) Is it efficient to store IPs like that?

2) If yes, then how can I update each time the date and IP, so it won't erase the previous ones?

3) If instead of using the same table, I will create a new one, say "users_IPs", and then will store the user-id there, and then will use the same TEXT(JSON-like format) to store the IPs, would that be more efficient?

If you think there's a better way of dealing with this kind of thing, you're most welcome to share you thoughts.

Comment: You would be better off just making another table and store the ip with the userid and date, no need for json you can just use varchar and dateTime.

Comment: so I will be creating each time the user is logging a new row with the same user-id and a new date and ip? is that what you meant, Joseph_J?

Comment: yup, this will also make querying the results easier too.

Comment: there is no reason to store IP each time with date, only if you want to show the stats to that user of previous logins..... but if you only want to show him/last login time than simply update the single row when he login successfully..

Comment: Perhaps you're right, but it doesn't sound efficient... It would be filled very quickly if you have active users.

Comment: @Coffee  Why not just add the date with the other info.  Then you have the information if you need it later.  It's trivial at this point.  He can always query for the last date by userid to get the last login.

Comment: Coffee, I know that. I'm already storing the last login :) I want to store all the login activity(date and IP) of the user

Comment: @dekenici  You would have to have a crap ton of users for this to ever be a problem.

Comment: @Joseph_J storing only date also makes sense, but my question is why he want to create new row whenever user logs in, if I login 10 times a day, then will be 10 rows in database against my ip. now suppose if you have 10,000 users ... you are making your database more heavier.. which could cause affect on performance later

Comment: Joseph_J, I don't think so. it could be filled very, very quickly if you have, say 10,000 users with average 1 login in a day. It won't hold even a half of a year to store more than two million of records

Comment: Coffee, I don't :)

Comment: i dont know the scenario of your project exactly.. but you may store the login details for a month only for each user.. this could reduce the burden, and you will have your functionality functional too

Comment: The query gets called only when the user signs in to insert a new row, and get the users last login.  Then it's not needed for the rest the users time on the site.  Even with 2 million records, with an indexed DB that's not going to be a drain on the system.  So the login takes another second or two.  If you are concerned about performance and the table gets to big, save the table and start a new one.

Comment: Joseph_J, even with indexed DB, it will still need to search for all(!) the user-ids before finishing. Because the same user will logged into the DB with a gap(other users will be stored as well). Maybe it is a way to work with it, but I have reasonable doubts about it

Comment: Something to consider, your original design is not normalized which does come with its own problems. Adding JSON will still have it not normalized but also not relational

Comment: dekenici  If index a DB on the userid it will not have to search through all of the userid's, they will be indexed with a pointer telling the DB exactly where they are.  On a million record DB (with a theoretically perfect index) will only take 20 comparisons to find the userid's.

Comment: aprokryfos, could you please explain this in more details? How would you approach this / design it?

Answer (score 0):

Storing logs as JSON is neither efficient nor practical.

List of IPs as JSON string will take more disk space. At the same time such list is harder to search - at some point you may want use these logs to search users by IP or display logins-per-day statistics. This will be much harder if you will need to operate on JSON string than separate table with proper schema.

This also will slow down updates. For each new IP you need to update the whole JSON, so if you have a 100 saved IPs, and want to add a new one, you need to save in database JSON with 101 records. Inserting single record in separate table should be much more efficient (and easier to prune old data).

So unless:
a) you want to keep this simple and you don't want to store a large amount of data in this way nor update it often,
b) you need to access user logs often and `select` performance is much more important than logs updating,
I would recommend creating a separate table for login logs, where each row represents single login event. It is more safe solution - scales better and it is more pragmatic.